# How can I jump to a file and line number from a list in a buffer?

Tags: files

I have a buffer with content like:

```
src/file4.rs:9
src/file4.rs:33
src/file4.rs:64
```

I'd like to be able to put my cursor on a line and jump to the appropriate file / line in the other window, just like compilation-mode would. However, this buffer contains files/lines that I've generated via other means, it is not the output of a script.

Comment: Are those relative paths?

Comment: @Dan Yes, but I can easily tweak them to be absolute.

Comment: See also `next-error-function` and command `next-error`. The idea is that you can define a suitable `next-error-function` value for your buffer/mode, and then take advantage of everything Emacs provides for `next-error`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually re-use compilation mode without doing much work.  Say, for example, you are saving the file you generate into `foo.errors`.

1. Add `-*- mode: compilation -*-` in the first line.
2. Format your errors, for example, like this: `<path to file>: line <line number>:` (this is covered by this entry `(bash "^\\([^: \n\t]+\\): line \\([0-9]+\\):" 1 2)` in the `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`.
3. When you load up the buffer, the compilation mode will be set automatically, and the lines in the format above will be highlighted. When you press <kbd>RET</kbd> on them, the file under point will be opened on the line specified.

You can also set the directory in the [local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) but its unnecessary, if the path to the file is absolute or you will always use paths relative to the `foo.errors`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a command I whipped up (note that the regexp is not particularly sophisticated).  I can't really test it, unfortunately, so you may have to tinker with it.

```
(defun jump-to-file-and-line ()
  "Reads a line in the form FILENAME:LINE and, assuming a
relative path, opens that file in another window and jumps to the
line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((line (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))
    (string-match "\\(.*\\):\\([0-9]+\\)" line)
    (let ((file (match-string 1 line))
          (lnum (match-string 2 line)))
      (when (and file (file-exists-p (concat default-directory file)))
        (find-file-other-window (concat default-directory file))
        (and lnum (goto-line (string-to-number lnum)))))))
```

Comment: I also used `local-set-key` to bind Enter to the function.

Comment: Of course, I really want the *full power* of being able to jump to the next / previous location and maybe some highlighting, but I'll call that scope creep!

Comment: Really nice, just to mention that `forward-line` function is preferred to `goto-line` function.