# How to show the output of a command in a quick-fix window?

Tags: buffers, call-process

If I have a command that runs and generates the following output.

```
/path/to/file.rst:1
/another/path/to/file.rst:42
```

How would I call the command so a buffer is opened and clicking on the line jumps to the file?

Comment: This looks similar to the `compile` output which has built-in support to jump to lines in the relevant source code files; e.g., `(compile "command line")` ...

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-can-i-jump-to-a-file-and-line-number-from-a-list-in-a-buffer).